# Flexget RSS for torrent

Tags: download, automation

```
presets:
```

Preset_name:
    regexp:
      accept:
        - DVDRip
    download: ~/torrent/watch

tasks:
  Task_name:
    rss: http://
    preset:
      - Preset_name

Hello I'm using this config in flexget. Is there a way to specify somewhere to download only DVDRip that was posted in the last 2 hours? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To download only DVDrip, it's easy, you can use the "quality" filter wich is very simple to use:

```
quality: dvdrip
```

And to get only those posted in the last 2 hours, maybe you can try to use the input "discover" with the filter "only_new":

http://flexget.com/wiki/Plugins/discover

http://flexget.com/wiki/Plugins/only_new